# OneToOneField error

Tags: python, django

I am working on a user registration form, the form is made up of two Django forms, namely, the CustomUserForm and the CompanyProfileForm (i.e. ModelForm). These forms are connected via a OneToOneField that is situated in the CompanyProfile model, as shown in the code below.

```js
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    companyName = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    companyRegNum = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Below is my CompanyProfileForm

```js
class CompanyProfileForm(ModelForm):
    # keywordsContainer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={
    #     'id': 'keywordsContainer_id'
    # }))
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'companyName': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'id': 'companyNameId',
                            'name': 'companyName',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter company name'
                        }),
            'companyRegNum': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'id': 'companyRegNumId',
                            'name': 'companyRegNum',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter company reg number'
                        }),
            'contactNumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control input_field',
                            'id':'contactNum',
                            'name': 'contactNumber',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter contact number'
                        }),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'id': 'addressId',
                            'name': 'address',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter the address'
                        }),
            'areaCode': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'id': 'areaCodeId',
                            'name': 'areaCode',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter the areaCode'
                        }),
            'deliveryEmails': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control textInput',
                            'id': 'deliveryEmailId',
                            'name': 'deliveryEmails',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter the email address(s)'
                        }),
            'provinces': forms.Select(attrs={
                           'multiple': 'multiple',
                           'id': 'provinces'
                       }),
            'tenderCategory': forms.Select(attrs={
                           'multiple': 'multiple',
                           'id': 'catSelect'
                       }),
            'keywords': forms.Select(attrs={
                           'id': 'keywords_id'
                       }),
            'package': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={
                            'id': 'package_id'
                        }),
            'pymntMethod': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={
                            'id': 'pymntType',
                            'value': '3'
                        }),
            'termsAndConditions': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
                            'id': 'termsAndConditions'
                        })
        }
```

End this is my View.

```js
def subscribe_view(request, billing_cycle, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userRegForm = CustomUserForm(request.POST)
        companyForm = CompanyProfileForm(request.POST)
        print(companyForm)

        if userRegForm.is_valid() and companyForm.is_valid():
            user = userRegForm.save()
            compProfile = companyForm.save(commit=False)
            if compProfile.user_id is None:
                compProfile.user_id = user.id
            compProfile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_account/dashboard')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
    else:
        package = Packages.objects.get(pk=pk)

        if billing_cycle == '1' or billing_cycle == '0':
            b_cycle = billing_cycle
        else:
            b_cycle = '0'

        userRegForm = CustomUserForm()
        companyProfileForm = CompanyProfileForm()
        companyProfileForm.fields["pymntMethod"].initial = 3
        companyProfileForm.fields["package"].initial = pk
        #companyProfileForm.fields["keywordsContainer"].initial = 'zzz'
        #companyProfileForm.fields["user"].initial = 0
        bankingDetailsForm = BankingDetailsForm()

        args = {'userRegForm': userRegForm,
                'package': package,
                'billing_cycle': b_cycle,
                'companyProfileForm': companyProfileForm,
                'bankingDetailsForm': bankingDetailsForm
        }
        args.update(csrf(request))
        return render(request, 'user_account/subscribe.html', args)
```

Now my problem is that the OneToOneField in the CompanyProfile model above is required since it also acts as a primary key field which causes a problem on this line

```js
if userRegForm.is_valid() and companyForm.is_valid():
```

in the view, because OneToOneField of the CompanyProfileModel must wait until the User is saved before the OneToOneField is given a value. Because of this the CompanyProfileForm validates to false as it keeps saying user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True) is required.

HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS PROBLEM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just exclude the user field from the CompanyProfileForm. You are already setting it on save, so it doesn't need to be in the form at all.

```
class CompanyProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyProfile
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about doing something like this ?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        userRegForm = CustomUserForm(request.POST)
        companyForm = CompanyProfileForm(request.POST)
        print(companyForm)

        if userRegForm.is_valid():
            user = userRegForm.save()
        else:
            #take user to somewhere to fix this
            pass

        companyForm.user = user
        if companyForm.is_valid():
            compProfile = companyForm.save(commit=False)
            if compProfile.user_id is None:
                compProfile.user_id = user.id
            compProfile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_account/dashboard')
        else:
            #You might want to delete user if things dont go well.  
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```